# Illustrator CS6: pixelated windows screenshots?

Tags: screenshot, adobe-illustrator

I seem to be having a problem exporting images from photoshop and preserving their image quality as much as possible.

They look fine in windows image preview and as well inside photoshop and I have tried all sorts of different settings and combinations. The moment the screensht of an app I have been building for a longtime is placed into a poster I am creating using AI:CS6, all image quality is lost, the entire image is pixelated and has jagged edges with hardly any anti aliasing going on whatsoever from what I can tell.

Screenshot of AI:CS6
[image: Screenshot of AI:CS6]

What it looks like inside PS:CS6
[image: What it looks like inside PS:CS6]

*I hope you can agree there is a distinct loss of quality from the PS to AI*

Comment: Image size in AI does not match the original (it's resized).

Comment: OK but what do I do about that then? Even when I resize the image it still looks poor!

Comment: Set zoom to 100% in AI and you'll see the original quality.